# Convert list of set into dictionary

Tags: python

```
fruits = [{'apple', 'banana', 'berry'}, 
          {'strawberry', 'orange'}]
fruit_dict = {}    
group_id = 0
while group_id < len(fruits):
    for fruit in fruits:    
        fruit_dict[fruit] = group_id
    group_id += 1
```

I am trying to create a dictionary where I can assign group id to a list of sets 'fruits'. But I keep getting
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'` from the line `for fruit in fruits:` .
Expected output:

```
fruit_dict = { {'apple', 'banana', 'berry'}: 0, 
          {'strawberry', 'orange'}: 1 }
```

Comment: But if you still need set functionality and want to use them as keys, you can use [frozensets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). Of course it has less functionality, because it's immutable, but maybe it suits your case

Comment: Usually IDs work the other way around. You look up the ID and get the data/item.

Comment: Well yes, all in all it depends on what you are trying to do here. There is not enough information to find a *real* solution

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, `set`s are not hashable and therefore can't be used as dictionary keys. You can use other hashable types like [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)s or [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)s. You then just need to convert your sets, and you can do it easily with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (instead of maintaining an index in a `while` loop):

```py
fruit_dict = {}    

for group_id, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    fruit_dict[frozenset(fruit)] = group_id
```

Or just a dict-comp:

```
fruit_dict = {frozenset(fruit): group_id for group_id, fruit in enumerate(fruits)}
```

Comment: The only limitation to that is that the tuple cannot contain types that aren't hashable, i.e. other sets, lists, etc. What about just switching the key/value pairs around?

Comment: @gmdev True, it all goes down to the fact that "everything in a dict's key need to be hashable". As to your second point, I was just following the OP's requirement. I will also argue that this dict is not at all necessary as you already have the sets with their indices in the list. Again, that depends on the OP's requirement and use-case...

Answer (score 0):

`set` objects are unhashable. To use sets as dictionary keys, you want to use `frozenset`, which are just like sets except they are immutable and hashable.

Also, your while-loop doesn't do what you want it to do. You'll want to use `enumerate` instead.

```
fruits = [{'apple', 'banana', 'berry'},
          {'strawberry', 'orange'}]
fruit_dict = {}
for i, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
  fruit_dict[frozenset(fruit)] = i
```

Now printing `fruit_dict` will give you the following output:

```
{frozenset({'berry', 'banana', 'apple'}): 0, frozenset({'orange', 'strawberry'}): 1}
```

Not exactly as you requested, but as long as you don't try to modify the dictionary keys, it should work the same.